# TypeScript didnt get to build?

Tags: javascript, typescript, build, sublimetext

I have a very simple TypeScript file `Car.ts` as below

```
class Car 
{
    engineType: number;
    constructor(engine : number){
        this.engineType = engine;
    }
}
```

And I have a sublime-build file with below content

```
{
    "selector":"source.ts",
    "cmd": ["tsc", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(.+?) \\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\): (.+)$"
}
```

I'm expecting to be able to utilize the build file by pressing `ctrl+B`, and it should convert the ts file to javascript, but nothing happened?

Alternatively, may i know how to build the TS file to convert to JS file using normal text editor?

Comment: I'd recommend adopting a [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) at that point you can have your task be `tsc` alone and the compiler will handle the file inputs and options. Don't know anything about sublime though, sorry

Comment: First try to compile it in the command line to see if it is working: `tsc Car.ts`?

Comment: @unional: Yes it's working fine

Comment: If you haven't tried it, the Microsoft TypeScript plugin for Sublime Text has build integration that automatically builds single files or via your `tsconfig.json`, plus some other features. May be worth looking into to see if it's of any use. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TypeScript